# Concatenate the numbers between 1 and N and see if it is divisible by 3

Tags: python, concatenation, division

I'm trying to make a program that basically works like this:
I ask for a number, and from that number I must form a number N by concatenating all the numbers between 1 and N. For example, if I enter a 12, the number N will be 123456789101112, or if I enter a 6, the number would be 123456. Once N has been formed, I must return "YES" on the screen in the case that N is divisible by 3 and “NO” in the case that it is not.

This is what I have:

```
n = int(input("Enter a number:"))

for x in range (n + 1):
if(n%3==0):
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

I just started using Python and I don't know what I'm doing wrong, if someone can give me a hand I would be very grateful!

Comment: Could you please clarify one section? You used N to mean two things, 12 and 123456789101112. First - if N is 12 and the output is `123456789101112` are you looking to see if 12 is divisible by 3 or if `123456789101112` is divisible by 3?

Comment: I want to know if N (in the case you are asking, N would be `123456789101112`) is divisible by 3. N is the concatenation between 1 and the number I have asked them to introduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it using the algorithm you describe, then a simple (but not very fast) way of doing it would be so:

```py
n = int(input("Enter a number:"))    # get the number

stringNumber = ""
for x in range(1, n+1):
  stringNumber += str(x)             # join the string version of numbers 1...n into a string

intNumber = int(stringNumber)        # convert the string concatenation into an int

if (intNumber % 3 == 0):             # check if the int is divisible by 3
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

You can speed-up the string concatenation by using `join()` if you wish:

```py
stringNumber = "".join([str(digit) for digit in range(1,n+1)])
```

the result is the same

However, you might also notice that a number is divisible by 3 if the sum of its digits is divisible by 3, so you can use an algorithm like this:

```py
n = int(input("Enter a number:"))    # get the number

sumOfDigits = sum([digit for digit in range(1,n+1)])   # sum numbers 1...n

if (sumOfDigits % 3 == 0):             # check if the int is divisible by 3
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

Comment: Your answer is just perfect! Not only have I learned to concatenate numbers, but your calculation to see if it is divisible by 3 is more professional. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The answer will be :

```
if n%3 != 1:
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

**Reason**

Every number is one of the three types `(3*k+1)`, `(3*k+2)` or `(3*k)`. A number is divisible by 3 if the sum of its digits is divisible by 3 a.k.a. it is a `(3*k)` type of number.

If input is 1. Then N will be 1 which  is a `(3*k+1)` type of number so it is not divisible by 3.

When input is 2. Then N will be 12 which is divisible by 3.

When input is 3. Then N will be 123 which is divisible by 3.

Similarly, when input is 4. Then N will be 1234 which is not divisible by 3.

If you go one you realise that N will be divisible by 3 whenever the input is not a `(3*k+1)` type of number.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution. It shows how you can test `n` the input and `val` the concatenated value

```
n = int(input("enter a number: "))
# This line creates a list of numbers and
# then concatenates them as a new number in string format
val = "".join(str(x) for x in range(1, n + 1))

print(f"Is {n} divisible by 3? ")
print("no" if int(n) % 3 else "yes")

print(f"Is {val} divisible by 3? ")
print("no" if int(val) % 3 else "yes")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a one-line tertiary operation with a list comprehension to do this as well.

```
def check():
    n = int(input("Enter a number:"))
    return 'Yes' if int(''.join([str(i) for i in range(1,n+1)]))%3==0 else 'No'

check()
```

```
Enter a number:12

'Yes'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a range to produce numbers from 1 to N, convert them to strings and concatenate them:

```
x    = 12
N    = int("".join(map(str,range(1,x+1))))
div3 = N%3 == 0

print("Is",N,"divisible by 3?",["NO","YES"][div3]) 

# Is 123456789101112 divisible by 3? YES
```